# Can I use the ST-LINK for programming and debugging STR7 Chips?

Tags: stm32, embedded, debugging, jtag

Is it possible to use the ST-LINK V3 to program and debug STR7 Familiy chips? If not, what programmer can I use?

Comment: I don't see why not. Moreover, I used OpenOCD with a limited variant of ST-LINK (that came with some eval board) to program and debug even non-ST processors.

Comment: I forgot how it goes, and there was a good instruction (sorry about my attitude) to use ST-LINK for generic (almost) JTAG application for ARM processor (that I needed for Raspi-4). Keep searching online.

Comment: @jay Should be pretty easy with OpenOCD. I used it with TI BeagleBone board. Pretty much edit the "standard" BB config file and replace the included JTAG adapter config with ST-link config.